# How to create the 5NN model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've problem with `construct the 5NN model. Report it's success rate on the testing sample. Report it's rate of false-positive and false-negative predictions.`.

Firstly, I need to download the data on Iris classification and paste headlines.

```py
        import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
    
    %matplotlib inline
    
    df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header = None)
    df_names = ['sepal length in cm', 'sepal width in cm', 'petal length in cm', 'petal width in cm', 'class']
    df.columns = df_names
    df
```

Secondly, I should create a scatterplot of data using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` in a following manner:

```
    * for x and y coordinates use sepal length and width respectively
    * for size use the petal length
    * for alpha (opacity/transparency) use the petal width
    * illustrate iris belonging to each class by using 3 distinct colours (RGB for instance, but be creative if you want)
    * *some columns will need to be scaled, to be passed as parameters; you might also want to scale some other columns to increase the readability of the illustration.
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')

%matplotlib inline

# dataset-df

x1 = [4.3, 7.9, 5.84, 0.83, 0.7826]

y1 = [2.0, 4.4, 3.05, 0.43, -0.4194]
 
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c ="red",alpha = 1,
            linewidth = 2,
            marker ="s",
            s = [1.0, 6.9, 3.76, 1.76, 0.9490])

plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.show()
```

Then, I should standardize the explanatory variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')

%matplotlib inline

df_new = (df-df.mean())/df.std()
df_new
```

After that, I dropped the column "class".

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')

%matplotlib inline
df.drop(columns='class', inplace=True)
```

At that moment, I separated the sample into 85/15 training/testing sets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
plt.style.use('seaborn')
%matplotlib inline
 
# get the locations
x = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
 
# split the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.05, random_state=0)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.15,random_state=123)

X_train
```

Now, I attempted write the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
plt.style.use('seaborn')
%matplotlib inline


X_test = df[np.invert(df.index)].iloc[:,:1].copy()]
```

However, I always have this problem:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3972/389539265.py in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13 X_test = df[np.invert(df.index)].iloc[:,:1].copy()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3462             if is_iterator(key):
   3463                 key = list(key)
-> 3464             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3465 
   3466         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  -1,   -2,   -3,   -4,   -5,   -6,   -7,   -8,   -9,  -10,\n            ...\n            -141, -142, -143, -144, -145, -146, -147, -148, -149, -150],\n           dtype='int64', length=150)] are in the [columns]"
```

Could you advise me on how to sort it out this problem and complete my task?

In addition, I copied the data from `iris.names`:

```
1. Title: Iris Plants Database
    Updated Sept 21 by C.Blake - Added discrepency information

2. Sources:
     (a) Creator: R.A. Fisher
     (b) Donor: Michael Marshall (MARSHALL%PLU@io.arc.nasa.gov)
     (c) Date: July, 1988

3. Past Usage:
   - Publications: too many to mention!!!  Here are a few.
   1. Fisher,R.A. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems"
      Annual Eugenics, 7, Part II, 179-188 (1936); also in "Contributions
      to Mathematical Statistics" (John Wiley, NY, 1950).
   2. Duda,R.O., & Hart,P.E. (1973) Pattern Classification and Scene Analysis.
      (Q327.D83) John Wiley & Sons.  ISBN 0-471-22361-1.  See page 218.
   3. Dasarathy, B.V. (1980) "Nosing Around the Neighborhood: A New System
      Structure and Classification Rule for Recognition in Partially Exposed
      Environments".  IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine
      Intelligence, Vol. PAMI-2, No. 1, 67-71.
      -- Results:
         -- very low misclassification rates (0% for the setosa class)
   4. Gates, G.W. (1972) "The Reduced Nearest Neighbor Rule".  IEEE 
      Transactions on Information Theory, May 1972, 431-433.
      -- Results:
         -- very low misclassification rates again
   5. See also: 1988 MLC Proceedings, 54-64.  Cheeseman et al's AUTOCLASS II
      conceptual clustering system finds 3 classes in the data.

4. Relevant Information:
   --- This is perhaps the best known database to be found in the pattern
       recognition literature.  Fisher's paper is a classic in the field
       and is referenced frequently to this day.  (See Duda & Hart, for
       example.)  The data set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each,
       where each class refers to a type of iris plant.  One class is
       linearly separable from the other 2; the latter are NOT linearly
       separable from each other.
   --- Predicted attribute: class of iris plant.
   --- This is an exceedingly simple domain.
   --- This data differs from the data presented in Fishers article
    (identified by Steve Chadwick,  spchadwick@espeedaz.net )
    The 35th sample should be: 4.9,3.1,1.5,0.2,"Iris-setosa"
    where the error is in the fourth feature.
    The 38th sample: 4.9,3.6,1.4,0.1,"Iris-setosa"
    where the errors are in the second and third features.  

5. Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)

6. Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class

7. Attribute Information:
   1. sepal length in cm
   2. sepal width in cm
   3. petal length in cm
   4. petal width in cm
   5. class: 
      -- Iris Setosa
      -- Iris Versicolour
      -- Iris Virginica

8. Missing Attribute Values: None

Summary Statistics:
             Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation
   sepal length: 4.3  7.9   5.84  0.83    0.7826   
    sepal width: 2.0  4.4   3.05  0.43   -0.4194
   petal length: 1.0  6.9   3.76  1.76    0.9490  (high!)
    petal width: 0.1  2.5   1.20  0.76    0.9565  (high!)

9. Class Distribution: 33.3% for each of 3 classes.
```

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your code, but why would you expect any of the column names of df to be the inverse of the index values?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did it, because it's my next task.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "You did it because it's your next task.". Can you explain what this section of code "df[np.invert(df.index)]" is supposed to be doing?